# deploying web services through google application engine

Tags: java, web-services, google-app-engine

I have web service that is up and running that is in other words it is publish on my tomat on port 8080 and I can hit it through my browser now I want that my webservice to be get published on cloud so that I can pass wsdl uri to any one in the world and he can access my wsdl.I want to achieve this through google application Engine , Please advise how to achieve this..!!

Answer (score 1):

You could just if you are using pure-Java to build those WebServices. No Axis or CXF allowed in GAE.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/soap

And why not REST services?

Comment: Well dude I have build a webservice on cxf2 already and it is now running perfectly on my local at tomcat and I can check the wsdl by hitting at toomcat serverand now I want to make this webservice means hosting it on cloud so that any body can access my wsdl it should ot be loal..!! Please advise how to achieve this..!!

Comment: Maybe you should try another Cloud provider instead of AppEngine.
It will work with Heroku, Openshift, CloudFoundry, JElastic, etc